# Checking if a string contains a dot

Tags: java, string

Today I was trying to detect if a string contains a dot, but my code isn't working

```
 String s = "test.test";
 if(s.contains("\\.")) {
     System.out.printLn("string contains dot");
 }
```

Comment: had same issue, upvote

Comment: It's not a regex, a simple String. Use "." only

Comment: Note for those landing on this question in 2019: The function given in the top comment (`.contains()`) has been deprecated in favor of `.includes()`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`contains()` method of String class does not take regular expression as a parameter, it takes normal text.

```
String s = "test.test";

if(s.contains("."))
{
    System.out.println("string contains dot");
}
```

Answer (score 16):

[`String#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) receives a plain `CharacterSequence` e.g. a `String`, not a regex. Remove the `\\` from there.

```
String s = "test.test";
if (s.contains(".")) {
    System.out.println("string contains dot");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You only need

```
s.contains (".");
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you will need to find a character and do something with it, a similar check can also be done using `.indexOf('.')`, for instance:

```
"Mr. Anderson".indexOf('.'); // will return 2
```

The method will return the index position of the dot, if the character doesn't exist, the method will return -1, you can later do a check on that.

```
if ((index = str.indexOf('.'))>-1) { .. do something with index.. }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String k="test.test";
    String pattern="\\.";
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m=p.matcher(k);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Contains a dot");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to check with a `.contains()` statement.

**Note:** `.contains()` works only for strings.

**From**

```java
 String s = "test.test";
 if(s.contains("\\.")) {
     System.out.printLn("string contains dot");
 }
```

**To**

```java
String s = "test.test";
 if(s.contains(".")) {
     System.out.printLn("string contains dot");
 }
```

Do like this to check any symbol or character in a string.